# Overlay text files on top of each other and output to another text file in C++?

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

I am busy writing a program that is constructing minions (from Despicable Me) using ASCII of the minions that are in a text file. What I want to do is be able to have the user input what features he/she wants the minion to have. Then, from this, the program will "decorate" this minion by putting the text files together as the minion he/she wanted.

For example:

The user inputs that he wants a `tall minion with one eye and a big smile` - I will have the features of the minions already created in text files with certain parts missing from the minion. What I want to do is "overlay" the tall minion text file on top of the one eyed minion text file, on top of the big smile minion text file so in the end it creates a full minion.

I was just wondering if this is possible to do? Could I construct minions like this or would I have to do it the hard way by changing the format of the text files completely to add in features using fstream.

This link is where these minion ascii is from: http://textart4u.blogspot.com/2013/08/minion-what-text-art-despicable-me.html

Comment: Almost sounds like you need a CSV format, like `tall, one eye, big smile` such that features are 'categorized' into specified columns of the CSV, and then you can take the user input and translate it into this type of CSV data.  Then you would have a database of minion texts associated with keyed features of minions.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that kind of thing but realised that there are so many options for this because there are many different kinds of features that a minion can have. But thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the issue of minions of different dimensions for a moment. Assuming you have some character that represents transparency (or not-part-of-the-feature characters, e.g. white space), you can assign each feature a depth, iterate over the selected feature files from background to foreground, and write each non-transparent character in the correct position to an ongoing minion text file.

Here's some very rough pseudo code that assumes each file has the same number of lines.

```
Write minion base (most background) to output file.

For each feature file, from background to foreground:
    Seek to beginning of output file.

    For each line in feature file / output file:
        Extend output file's line to match feature file's line if necessary.

        For each character in line of feature file / output file:
            If feature file's char is not transparent:
                Overwrite current char in output file with current char in feature file.
```

If this is not flexible enough, you can assign each character of a feature file a depth, and iterate over the feature files in any order, only overwriting the current output file's character if the feature file's character is closer to the foreground. You'd need to encode the depth somehow -- using a corresponding depth file is an obvious way.

The tricky part might be supporting minions of different dimensions. To handle that, it may be enough to specify vertical/horizontal offsets for every feature / minion body type combination, and use that to adjust where you write the feature in the ongoing output file. Alternatively, it may be easier to duplicate each feature file with appropriate modifications to make it fit a given minion body type. Both of these methods require some manual grunt-work, but if you don't have to worry about that many body types, these simple methods are probably preferable to more complicated but flexible methods.

Comment: After reading this, this definitely would work, but I decided to read in the contents of the template minion into a vector and then read in eg the eyes and replace the contents of the vector where the eyes should be then output that vector to a new file, it seems to work perfectly. Thanks for the answer though :)